# Getting null when using match brackets in monaco editor

Tags: monaco-editor, visual-studio-monaco, ngx-monaco-editor

Hope you are going well.

I have used `editor.getmodel().matchBrackets(5);` then I getting `null`.

What I am trying for is, I want to get the range from 5th line of opening bracket to closing bracket.

Is the above is correct for, what I am trying.

Answer (score 0):

Yes me too need the same answer but i got warning that it is not clear 1 week ago

Comment: You are not answering the question. Maybe you should put it in the comment.